# top -H shows few thread IDs that do not appear in jstack output

Tags: java, performance, centos, jstack

I am trying to investigate why my jboss is taking up 600% CPU (running on CentOS 5).

I run `top -H` and try to compare the result with `jstack` output. Most of the thread IDs that come from top appear in the output of jstack but unfortunately the threads that take up most of the CPU are not listed there.

Because the output is very long I am only listing part of it here.

```
$top -b -n1 -H -p <jboss pid>

top - 08:04:58 up 73 days, 19:50,  1 user,  load average: 5.72, 5.97, 5.95
Tasks: 128 total,   6 running, 122 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 63.6%us,  1.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 34.2%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32946160k total, 32545228k used,   400932k free,    86776k buffers
Swap: 34996216k total,      136k used, 34996080k free, 21577176k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                          
12908 jboss     16   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S 71.5 27.4 146:45.68 java                                                                                                                             
12903 jboss     16   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S 69.5 27.4 146:36.08 java                                                                                                                             
12904 jboss     16   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S 69.5 27.4 146:39.63 java                                                                                                                             
12905 jboss     16   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S 69.5 27.4 146:44.46 java                                                                                                                             
12906 jboss     16   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S 69.5 27.4 146:53.94 java                                                                                                                             
12907 jboss     16   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S 69.5 27.4 146:39.18 java                                                                                                                             
12914 jboss     16   0 9488m 8.6g  18m R 27.8 27.4  36:26.64 java                                                                                                                             
12901 jboss     25   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S  0.0 27.4   0:00.00 java                                                                                                                             
12902 jboss     25   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S  0.0 27.4   0:00.05 java                                                                                                                             
12909 jboss     23   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S  0.0 27.4  76:34.09 java                                                                                                                             
12910 jboss     23   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S  0.0 27.4  76:33.49 java                                                                                                                             
12911 jboss     15   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S  0.0 27.4 257:10.35 java                                                                                                                             
12915 jboss     15   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S  0.0 27.4   0:06.63 java                                                                                                                             
12916 jboss     15   0 9488m 8.6g  18m S  0.0 27.4   0:19.61 java  
more lines....
```

The jstack outpout is as follows

```
# /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/jstack -F 3362

Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 13055: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=415 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run() @bci=11, line=441 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=662 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 12996: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=415 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run() @bci=11, line=441 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=662 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 12994: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=415 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run() @bci=11, line=441 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=662 (Interpreted frame)
```

more stacks....

The thread IDs in the output of `jstack` also appear in the output of `top` but the thread IDs from top *that are most CPU intensive* (1903-1908) do not appear in the output of jstack.

I thought these can be GC threads but I can't find anything to prove this.

Any idea why I don't see all the threads in jstack or what I can do to see the missing threads?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am currently having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run jstack under the jboss owner. This way you'll get more threads as an output. By issuing

```
jstack -l 12345
```

I got

```
 "Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f976c0d3000 nid=0x1f56a runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

note the nid is the hex representation of thread id got from top -H

Answer (score 0):

use jstack -m，can show threads from native(C/C++)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).